# Shrink LUKS and btrfs not using LVM

Tags: btrfs, luks

I have been all over Google and can only find directions for LVM on LUKS, or otherwise focused on `ext4` but I have a btrfs on a LUKS paritition. There is plenty of advice for growing a LUKS. As for shrinking it LUKS takes blocks whereas btrfs is more user friendly.

I have resized my btrfs and shrunk it by 1000G...

```
btrfs filesystem resize -1000g /slow
```

I however don't know how to calculate the blocks required to shrink the LUKS volume. I tried seeing if I could do it automatically...

```
cryptsetup resize /dev/mapper/bigslow
```

The `blockdev` command informs me that did nothing and the size remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
cryptsetup status $NAME | grep "sector size:"
sector size:  512
```

0.1Tb/512b=1,953,125s
Maybe minus one to be on the safe side.